# Returning a non-zero value for int main() in c++

Tags: c++, function, return-value

Int main is a function . And it's a integer function , so it should return a integer . When we want to close our program , we should type "return 0 ;" (in int main()) .
what if we type "return 34;" ? (returning a non-zero integer) . what will be happened ?
I tried it , i didn't see any difference . 
Where this returned integer will be used ?
If we return a non-zero integer , will it use more memory when program is closed ?

Comment: It will be used in the environment that started your program, mostly as a success (zero) or fail (non-zero) indicator.

Comment: Agree. Concrete code can be used to switch action in external script (BAT file in DOS/Windows) `if errorlevel   ...` Unix shell has similar (better) solution